# Android SDK update for libgdx

Tags: android, intellij-idea, sdk, libgdx, ubuntu-20.04

Today I try to generate project at libGDX, I installed android sdk via `sudo apt-get install android-sdk`

When I chose folder with installed android sdk at libGDX, I get this error:

***Please update your Android SDK, you need build tools 29.0.3***

So, I try to find how to update, but nothing help me. I guess i got sdk version about 25, how to check version also can't find. I use IntelliJ IDEA for developing and not like to install android studio, but if no another way, I will.

P.S. I have limited internet for now. This is the reason to ask Stackoverflow community. And sorry for that question.

Best regards.

Comment: You may check updates in "Settings | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings | Android SDK".

Comment: @y.bedrov I not found this section in my Settings. I thing should be some commandm but I have no idea what the command.

Comment: Do you have "Android" plugin installed in IDEA?

Comment: @y.bedrov I guess no(

Comment: You need to install it to develop Android applications in IDEA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be cmdline-tools in android sdk folder to download different versions of build tools.

Or you may download cmdline-tools directly from google ([link](https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads)). For example using curl: `curl https://link-to-latest-cmdline-tools --output tools.zip`
Then unpack it.

In cmdline-tools there is a `bin/sdkmanager`. It should allow you to load whatever version of build tools you need ([api info](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager)). But! I recommend if you downloaded and unpucked cmdline-tools manually, to download cmdline-tools again through sdkmanager to some folder. It will create *right folder structure* for android SDK else you will see errors trying to download build tools. After that use sdkmanager from that folder to download any version of build tools. Don't forget to add your new android sdk folder as ANDROID_HOME environment variable or something like that to make it visible for libgdx if it is necessary. Hope it is helpful.

Comment: @IvanHelsing as any executable file. just call it `$ ./sdkmanager`. if it is excutable(it should be), it will run. if not just call `sudo chmod +x ./sdkmanager` and try to call it again. [short article](https://medium.com/@peey/how-to-make-a-file-executable-in-linux-99f2070306b5)

Comment: Still nothing(((

Comment: @IvanHelsing what is the problem? Do you have cmdline-tools/bin folder? Do you have sdkmanager file in it? Are you able to run console in this folder and call sdkmanager? What does it say? Sorry I cant guess what does "Still nothing" mean)

Comment: @IvanHelsing Shell is perceiving command as name of binary. By default Shell is looking for binaries in folders which are listed in `Path` variable. If command(binary) isn't present in `Path` folders, shell throws `command not found`. You can run command not in Path if you will provide full path to binary. To do that you can `cd` to folder where binary is located and call `./sdkmanager` OR call it with full path `/home/..full_path.../bin/sdkmanager`. [Here is simple article explaining it.](http://teaching.idallen.com/cst8207/13w/notes/400_search_path.html#searching-for-command-names-in-path)